# My database shows 160 entries, but i only have 80

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax

As the title says, I am facing some issues on a website.
My DB counts 80 entries, but on the front page, when I try an ajax query to get the total number of entries, it responds with 160 .

Also, this problem appeared today although the website was working fine for the last 5 days..

Thanks for reading, and I apologize for my English level.

The ajax query:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#responsecontainer").load("countPost.php");
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
  $("#responsecontainer").load('countPost.php?randval='+ Math.random());
}, 1);
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

And the countPost.php:

```
$nb_messages_requete = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM mybase");
$nb_entrees = mysql_num_rows($nb_messages_requete); 
echo ''.$nb_entrees.''
```

Comment: Please show us the query that you execute, the ajax query and the server method that processes the ajax request

Comment: Please provide more details about your problem. What kind of database are you using? What kind of software for your website? At the moment, it sounds that your AJAX query is performed twice and the results are combined.

Comment: We need some more detail. What code does your Ajax call? What sql query is run to count the entries etc?

Comment: Edit your question with this info not comment it...

Comment: Are you sure there are only 80 rows in `mybase`?

Comment: I can't see how this could fail.

Comment: yep, i mean, the rows correspond to a "post" and each post are differents, but the output in the front of the website, shows each post twice ! and also multiply by two the total number of posts..

Comment: Instead of `echo ''.$nb_entrees.''` you could just write `echo $nb_entrees`. Also do you have a semi-colon at the line ending?

Comment: Well if the count was correct before and you made no changes to the code its logical to assume that something went wrong with the database count itself. Perform a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mydb` query through some external DB management tool (phpMyAdmin etc.) to get the actual number of records in your table.

Answer (score 3):

this because you are loading the `countPOST.php` two times

try this

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
 $("#responsecontainer").load('countPost.php?randval='+ Math.random());
}, 1);
 $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

if you mean do your code every one second then replace this `1` by `1000`

EDIT:

your cache looks desabled inside the function

try using it like that

```
     $.ajaxSetup ({
// Disable caching of AJAX responses */
cache: false
  });
    $(document).ready(function() {

var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
 $("#responsecontainer").load('countPost.php?randval='+ Math.random());
}, 1);

});
```

Comment: Yes but the first response to `countPost.php` is replaced right after 1ms so that is clearly not the problem.